# How to make Kotlin's inline class constructor visible to groovy?

Tags: kotlin, groovy

Kotlin 1.5 introduced value classes, for instance:

```
@JvmInline
value class ShopId(val raw: UUID)
```

In my setup I have groovy tests that attempt to create object of this type:

```
new ShopId(TestData.SHOP_ID)
```

However I get an error:

```
  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: domain.ShopId(UUID)
```

I guess error is related to the way signature of the inline class is generated, as per [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#mangling):

```
fun compute(x: UInt) will be represented as public final void compute-<hashcode>(int x)
```

So I tried to change mangling scheme with compiler arg:

```
 -Xuse-14-inline-classes-mangling-scheme,
```

sadly to no avail.

So my question is: is it possible to use kotlin inline classes from groovy? If so how do I do this?

Comment: I don't believe you can use value classes from Java/Groovy https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-6083